# ggplot: legend mixes 2 discree variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I try to plot time series (y=NDVI) along with quality flags (QF) as colored dots
at y=0. I want time series to be individually grouped and colored by observation site (ID). The problem is that I get one single legend mixing sites
and QF codes

data in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3180464/VN2014m.rda

```
attach("VN2014m.rda")
head(VN2014m)
str(VN2014m)
```

With either QF or ID the result is good (I omit styling axes etc):

```
ggplot(data=VN2014m) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=QF0,group=QF,col=QF))

ggplot(data=VN2014m) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI,group=ID,col=ID))
```

But with both ID and QF I get one single mixed legend

```
ggplot(data=VN2014m) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI,group=ID,col=ID)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=QF0,group=QF,col=QF))
```

Why? How can I get 2 separate legends, ID and QF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `shape=QF`?

```
ggplot(data=VN2014m) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Date,y=NDVI,group=ID,col=ID)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=Date,y=QF0,group=QF,shape=QF),
              size=3,position = position_jitter(height = .1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Should I understand that only one variable can be color-coded in each graphic? Is this the general rule?